# How to create multi direction table in flutter?

Tags: flutter, datatable, scrollable

I want to create an multi direction table view with a stricky column that should be in center. You can check it in video link below -

[Video for scrollable view in flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrG2t.jpg)

I tried [horizontal_data_table 4.1.2+2](https://pub.dev/packages/horizontal_data_table) but it contains only one table in right side with stick row header. But I want to show stricky column in center.

Answer (score 0):

you can use datagrid in syncfusion but it was commercial package https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/overview